# How does one operate over a subset of a vector?

Tags: rust

I understand how to operate on an entire vector, though I don't think this is idiomatic Rust:

```
fn median(v: &Vec<u32>) -> f32 {
    let count = v.len();
    if count % 2 == 1 {
        v[count / 2] as f32
    } else {
        (v[count / 2] as f32 + v[count / 2 - 1] as f32) / 2.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec![3, 7, 8, 5, 12, 14, 21, 13, 18];
    v1.sort();
    println!("{:.*}", 1, median(&v1));
}
```

But what if I want to operate on only half of this vector?  For example, the first quartile is the median of the lower half, and the third quartile is the median of the upper half.  My first thought was to construct two new vectors, but that did not seem quite right.

How do I get "half" a vector?

Comment: Regarding how to pass iterators please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969902/how-to-write-a-rust-function-that-takes-an-iterator). For your first question you can take a slice, eg `let slice = &v1[0..v1.len()/2]`

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). Since your "accept an iterator" question already has a duplicate, I've just removed it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned, you want to create a [*slice*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) using the [`Index` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) with a [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html):

```
let slice = &v1[0..v1.len() / 2];
```

This is yet another reason [why it is discouraged to accept a `&Vec`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423). The current code would require converting the slice into an allocated `Vec`. Instead, rewrite it to accept a slice:

```
fn median(v: &[u32]) -> f32 {
    // ...
}
```

Since you are likely interested in splitting a vector / slice in half and getting both parts, [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at) may be relevant:

```
let (head, tail) = v1.split_at(v1.len() / 2);
println!("{:.*}", 1, median(head));
println!("{:.*}", 1, median(tail));
```

Answer (score 2):

How to find the median on vector:

```rust
fn median(numbers: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    numbers.sort();
    let mid = numbers.len() / 2;

    if numbers.len() % 2 == 0 {
        mean(&vec![numbers[mid - 1], numbers[mid]]) as i32
    } else {
        numbers[mid]
    }

}
```

How to get `half` a vector:

- Use Slice:

```rust
let slice: &[i32] = &numbers[0..numbers.len() / 2];
```

- Creates a draining iterator

```rust
let half: Vec<i32> = numbers.drain(..numbers.len()/2).collect()
```

Comment: I like this answer, so I am wondering why it gets no love.  I'll assume the first code block works, it answers the implied question about idiomaticness.  The second "Slice" code is the same as part of the accepted answer, but it is missing the discouragement.  The third taught me a bunch.  The drain iterator removes the portion that it iterates over, in this case the original vector "numbers" will contain only the last half.  So this is similar to the split_at().

Comment: After all my noob analysis and study of the std::Vec documentation, I have decided that there are at least half a dozen ways of getting half a vector, including drain, split_at, split_off, resize, resize_default, and truncate.