# Is passing an iterator to a function as an argument an anti-pattern?

Tags: rust

Say I have a string, from which I make an iterator (cycle-able, peek-able) over its chars:

```
let hello = "hello";
let mut iterator = hello.chars().cycle().peekable;
```

I wanted to figure out what the type of `iterator` is, so I purposefully introduced an error:

`let mut iterator: usize = hello.chars().cycle().peekable;`

The compiler then informed me that the type of the right hand side is:

```
std::iter::Peekable<std::iter::Cycle<std::str::Chars<'_>>>
```

Wow, that's a mouthful. If I define a function like so:

```
fn foobar(x: std::iter::Peekable<std::iter::Cycle<std::str::Chars<'_>>>){
    // snip
}
```

I get an error like this:

```
error: underscore lifetimes are unstable (see issue #44524)
```

So, if I want to pass an iterator to a function, how should I do so? Or, is this something I should avoid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969902/how-to-write-a-rust-function-that-takes-an-iterator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so there are multiple aspects to this questions:

First of, you can avoid the compiler error by giving it an explicit lifetime:

```
fn foobar<'a>(mut x: std::iter::Peekable<std::iter::Cycle<std::str::Chars<'a>>>){
```

To the he second question, whether this is idiomatic or not, i'd say no, avoid this specific approach.

You can only pass in this specific Iterator chain - something else is not possible. But most of the times, your algorithm isn't interested in the specific combination, rather than the functionality to "produce" chars. Use [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969902/how-to-write-a-rust-function-that-takes-an-iterator) or`impl Trait` instead (if you have access to nightly rust).

Impl Trait is a feature, which allows hiding the specific type used. This specific feature, accepting impl traits in argument position landed as of a few days ago, at the time of writing. I made this quick sketch for demonstration purposes, [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1cbb705d059d6227f163479798654512&version=nightly)

```
#![feature(universal_impl_trait)]

fn main() {
    foo("hello".chars());
    foo("hello".chars().rev());
}

fn foo(x: impl Iterator<Item=char>) {
    let text: String = x.collect();
    println!("{}", &text)
}
```

**Edit**: You can use generics as well, see comments from nullqube and stefan

Comment: I don't think you should be giving answers that rely on experimental, non-stable features when there are perfectly good, stable alternatives.

Comment: @DK. Agreed, edited my answer yesterday to include generics as well. But the answer could do some more emphasis, what do you think?

Comment: Well, the question has been marked as a duplicate, so it's a bit of a moot point.