# What is the type/trait produced by calling the `chars` method on a string literal?

Tags: rust

Consider this piece of code:

```
struct Collector<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = char>,
{
    current: u32,
    right_neighbour: u32,
    counter: usize,
    iterator: T,
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = char>> Collector<T> {
    fn next(&self) -> u32 {
        self.iterator
            .next()
            .expect("failed to get next digit!")
            .to_digit(10)
            .expect("failed to prase char as digit!")
    }

    fn collect(&self) {
        self.current = self.right_neighbour;
        self.right_neighbour = self.next();
        self.counter = self.counter + 1;
    }

    fn initialize<U>(iterator: U) -> Collector<U>
    where
        U: Iterator<Item = char>,
    {
        let mut collector = Collector {
            current: 0,
            right_neighbour: 0,
            counter: 0,
            iterator: iterator,
        };

        collector.collect();

        collector
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numstr = "1111";

    let mut collector = Collector::initialize(numstr.chars().cycle().peekable());
}
```

It produces a type mismatch error:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `<_ as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == char`
  --> src/main.rs:46:25
   |
46 |     let mut collector = Collector::initialize(numstr.chars().cycle().peekable());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: required by `<Collector<T>>::initialize`
```

What is the type of `numstr.chars().cycle().peekable()`? The compiler tells me that its full type is:

```
std::iter::Peekable<std::iter::Cycle<std::str::Chars<'_>>>
```

I know that I can't use that type in the definition of my structs/functions, because [it doesn't have an explicit lifetime...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605913/is-passing-an-iterator-to-a-function-as-an-argument-an-anti-pattern)

How can I correctly write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the type/trait produced by calling the `chars` method on a string literal?

The [documentation for `str::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) tells you exactly what type it is:

```
fn chars(&self) -> Chars
```

> It produces a type mismatch error

Yes, because you haven't specified what the concrete type of `T` should be. You've introduced a completely separate generic type `U` and have no arguments or return types that reference `T`. The compiler has zero context to use to infer what `T` is.

> How can I correctly write this code?

Remove the useless extra type parameter:

```
struct Collector<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = char>,
{
    current: u32,
    right_neighbour: u32,
    counter: usize,
    iterator: T,
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = char>> Collector<T> {
    fn new(iterator: T) -> Collector<T> {
        let mut collector = Collector {
            current: 0,
            right_neighbour: 0,
            counter: 0,
            iterator: iterator,
        };

        collector.collect();

        collector
    }

    fn collect(&self) {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn next(&self) -> u32 {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numstr = "1111";

    let mut collector = Collector::new(numstr.chars().cycle().peekable());
}
```

I've removed the implementations of `next` and `collect` because they have other, unrelated errors that I don't care to fix. I also renamed `initialize` to `new`, as `new` is the standard constructor name in the absence of multiple constructors.

Of note is that the usage of `peekable` here is completely useless. The generic type `T` doesn't know that it's possible to call `peek` because there's no appropriate trait bound for such.

> because it doesn't have an explicit lifetime

You don't have to care about the lifetime, that will be covered by the generic. If your type needed to know that it was peekable, just put that in your struct:

```
struct Collector<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = char>,
{
    // ...
    iterator: std::iter::Peekable<T>,
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = char>> Collector<T> {
    fn new(iterator: T) -> Collector<T> {
        let mut collector = Collector {
            // ...
            iterator: iterator.peekable(),
        };

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

fn main() {
    // ...
    let mut collector = Collector::new(numstr.chars().cycle());
}
```