# How do I return an iterator over the keys of a HashSet from a trait method?

Tags: rust

A struct has a set of items I'd like to allow clients to iterate over. Here's an attempt:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub struct Foo<T: Eq + Hash> {
    items: HashSet<T>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + Eq + Hash> Foo<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Foo {
            items: HashSet::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn iterate<I>(&self) -> I
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
    {
        self.items.iter()
    }
}
```

This fails to compile, giving the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:19:9
   |
15 |     pub fn iterate<I>(&self) -> I
   |                                 - expected `I` because of return type
...
19 |         self.items.iter()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `std::collections::hash_set::Iter`
   |
   = note: expected type `I`
              found type `std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, T>`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

The return value from `HashSet::iter` method appears to act like an `Iterator` when, for example within a for loop. It seems like some kind of type coercion might be possible in my `iterate` method, but clearly the compiler has other ideas.

How can I specify a return type of `Iterator` in a function while returning the return value from a `HashSet` iterator?

In other words, I want to delegate iteration to `HashSet`. I'd like to avoid implementing a custom iterator to do this, but if that's the only way would be interested in seeing how it's done. I've been able to get this working by returning a `Box<dyn Iterator>`, but I'd like to avoid that approach as well if it's possible to work just with trait boundaries as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969944/54426).

One more requirement: the approach must work when the `iterate` method is declared on a trait. That appears to rule out an approach like:

```rust
pub trait FooTrait {
    fn iterate(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&T>;
}
```

Comment: From the duplicates: `fn iterate<I>(&self) -> std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, T>` or `fn iterate<I>(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &T> + '_>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `impl Iterator`:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a + Eq + Hash> Foo<T> {
    // ...

    pub fn iterate(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> {
        self.items.iter()
    }
}
```

The Rust book has [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#returning-types-that-implement-traits) covering it. It is defined and refined in [RFC 1522](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md), [RFC 1951](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1951-expand-impl-trait.md), and [RFC 2071](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2071-impl-trait-existential-types.md). It isn't all done yet and has [this tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63066).

Comment: Thanks, but in trying to simplify the question, I left out an important requirement: the iterate method needs to be declarable on a trait. I updated my question.